# Display favourite tags above related tags and displaying favourite tags within question pages?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, sidebar

I've not been active on SO for long, but now that I am getting more into it I'm finding myself flicking between specific tags checking for new questions. If I click on one tag to find that there are no new questions posted up, I'll move on to another tag, but in order to do this it either involves scrolling down a long list of related tags or navigating back to the homepage first.

Would it make more sense to display favourite tags *above* related tags? (Especially as related tags are inline and do not take up much space)
Equally, why aren't favourite tags displayed on the individual question pages?